# How to show SSRS reports with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS server which host reports, these reports have some parameters. In the SSRS, I can view the report and choose parameter values in the input controls.

Now I have a Vue.js and I need to load the SSRS reports in my page. And also, I need to customize the input control for the parameters. eg. I may need to use VUE.js to build a tree view for a report's parameter.

I think there should be a way to do so, but I don't find any example, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you review the [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) docs for SSRS reports.  That lets you basically load an iFrame with the report contents.  This will let you provide parameters to your report, and/or suppress user parameter selection, among many other things.

However, think through your "build a tree view for the report's parameter."  If you're asking to use the SSRS / report built-in parameter selection *outside* of the report viewer control - just don't.   It requires you to parse the report definition yourself, and that way there be dragons.  The syntax is deep and involved.

Instead, I suggest you hand roll your own tree view in Vue, then pass that as a parameter to the report, suppressing the HTML5 viewer's display of the parameter selection controls (using the URL querystring `&rc:Parameters=Collapsed`)